# Imap folder only returning a subset of emails with it

Tags: ruby, imap, gmail-imap

The following script only return 1000 messages within from the sent folder when the actual number of sent messages is in the 3000+

How can I get the rest of the messages?

```
username = ask("Enter your username:  ") { |q| q.echo = true }
password = ask("Enter your password:  ") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
look_in_folder = "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
save_to_folder = "/Users/penang/Desktop"

puts 'Starting...'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', '993', true)

puts "Logging in as #{username} ..."

imap.login(username, password)

imap.examine(look_in_folder)

mails = imap.uid_search(["FROM", "me"])
puts "Found #{mails.count} mail(s) in folder '#{look_in_folder}'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a solution

Go to **Settings > Labs** within Gmail and Enable **Advanced IMAP Controls**
[image]

You should now be able to change the folder size limits in **Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP**

Advanced IMAP Controls **Enabled**:
[image: Enabled]

Advanced IMAP Controls **Disabled (default)**:
[image: Disabled]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that there is not anything you can do, it has nothing to do with your script or Net::IMAP.  Google is not giving you more than 1000 mails for any folder via IMAP, and there are numerous complaints about this online (IE http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=2636f734144eeb28&hl=en)

Comment: is there an alternate protocol through which you can access the rest?

Comment: Not sure, you can try POP.  I think google does this on purpose as people fetching large amounts of IMAP mail from them do not really make them any advertising money.